# Error 13 call function with variant arrays in loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, parameters

I'd like to create a 2-dimensional Array from a Range in a EXCEL-sheet, that has several unshown (hidden) rows. First i create an Array in the overall-size of all visible rows and cols. Then i walk through the Range-Areas of the Overall-Range and try to assign the Value-Array of the specific Area to the target Array.

This all runs in a Loop over all Range-Areas. Extending the Target-Array works fine twelve times (iterations) then script breaks up with the nice

> error 13: type mismatch

in line `arr = WriteIntoArray(arr, arArr, targetcell)`.

A function call Eleven other times worked properly

Why is this? Are there some restricions regarding the size of variant-Arrays?

**My Code:**

This is the requested Sub, which is calling my function... (hope it makes it a bit clearer). Meanwhile thanks for hints, i'll try the announced one).

```html
Public Sub ProcessIngoingSheetdata(MonthPeriod As Integer, SourceImage As Variant, wsDestination As Worksheet)
' not declared yet - 2018-01-08

Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim arrDestination As Variant
Dim StartAdress(1) As Variant, EndAdress(2) As Variant

Debug.Print "In Sub 'ProcessIngoingSheetdata(MonthPeriod = " & MonthPeriod & "', ...)"

Set rngDestination = SetTargetRange(wsDestination, True) ' die Range für den Zielarray setzen
'rngDestination.Select
'wsDestination.Range("A1").Select

'MultipleRangeToArray
arrDestination = getMultiplerangeAsArray(rngDestination) ' MultipleRangeToArray(rngDestination)
Debug.Print "Boundaries(1) of array Destination: " & LBound(arrDestination, 1) & " to " & UBound(arrDestination, 1)
StartAdress(0) = LBound(arrDestination, 1)
StartAdress(1) = UBound(arrDestination, 1)
Debug.Print "Boundaries(2) of array Destination: " & LBound(arrDestination, 2) & " to " & UBound(arrDestination, 2)
EndAdress(0) = LBound(arrDestination, 2)
EndAdress(1) = UBound(arrDestination, 2)

Debug.Print "arrDestination: " & arrDestination(1, 2) & ", " & arrDestination(28, 2)

End Sub
```

```
Function getMultiplerangeAsArray(rngDestination) As Variant()

Dim arr() As Variant, arrExt As Variant, arArr As Variant, arrStart As Variant, r As Long, nr As Long, nc As Long, mar As Long, mac As Long
Dim ar As Range, C As Range, lu As Range, br As Range, cnum As Long, rnum As Long
Dim AbsoluteRowLU As Long, AbsoluteColLU As Long
Dim LastAbsoluteRowLU As Long, LastAbsoluteColLU As Long
Dim RelativeRowLU As Long, RelativeColLU As Long, RelativeRowBR As Long, RelativeColBR As Long
Dim LastRelativeRowLU As Long, LastRelativeColLU As Long, LastRelativeRowBR As Long, LastRelativeColBR As Long
Dim RelativeRowLevelStart As Long, RelativeColLevelStart As Long, RelativeRowLevelEnd As Long, RelativeColLevelEnd As Long
Dim RowHeight As Long, ColWidth As Long, NewRowHeight As Long, NewColWidth As Long
Dim cellDistance As Long
Dim PointerRow As Long
Dim col As Range

' set count of rows to maximum rows of a range-segment
nr = 1
nc = 1

LastRelativeRowBR = 1
LastRelativeColBR = 1

' setting on result-array
arrExt = getExtensionOfMultipleRange(rngDestination)
ReDim arr(arrExt(0), arrExt(1))

For Each ar In rngDestination.Areas

    With ar

        Set lu = .Cells(1)
        Set br = .Cells(.Cells.count)

        If ((Not lu Is Nothing) And (Not br Is Nothing)) Then
            RelativeRowLU = lu.row
            RelativeColLU = lu.column
            RelativeRowBR = br.row
            RelativeColBR = br.column

            AbsoluteRowLU = Range(.Cells(1).Address(0, 0)).row ' Range(.Cells(.Cells.count).Address(0, 0)).row
            AbsoluteColLU = Range(.Cells(1).Address(0, 0)).column

            Debug.Print "Current LU-Cell: '" & AbsoluteRowLU & " / " & AbsoluteColLU & "'."

            cellDistance = ((RelativeRowBR - RelativeRowLU) + 1)
            RowHeight = RowHeight + cellDistance

            cellDistance = ((RelativeColBR - RelativeColLU) + 1)
            ColWidth = ColWidth + cellDistance

        End If

    End With

    'Debug.Print "Left-Upper Cell: " & .Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & " with absolute row " & RelativeRowLU & " / col " & RelativeColLU

    ' check the new absolute-"position" of the current area / array and redim target-array
    If (AbsoluteRowLU > LastAbsoluteRowLU) Then
        RelativeRowLevelStart = AbsoluteRowLU
    End If
    If (AbsoluteColLU > LastAbsoluteColLU) Then
        RelativeColLevelStart = AbsoluteColLU
    End If

    ' to avoid errors also check if the new array is higher or more left (normaly impossible)
    If ((AbsoluteRowLU < AbsoluteRowLU) Or (AbsoluteColLU < LastAbsoluteColLU)) Then
        Debug.Print "getMultiplerangeAsArray(): Substantial error! New array-position is unclear? " & RelativeRowLU & " < " & LastRelativeRowBR & "? " & LastRelativeRowBR & " < " & LastRelativeColBR & " "
        MsgBox "getMultiplerangeAsArray(): Substantial error!", vbCritical
        End
    End If


    arArr = ar.Value
    Debug.Print "#" & nr & ": Größe arArr: (" & LBound(arArr, 1) & " to " & UBound(arArr, 1) & " / " & LBound(arArr, 2) & " to " & UBound(arArr, 2) & ")"

    ' getting now the requested size of the result-array to include the current range-array
    RelativeRowLevelEnd = ((RelativeRowLevelStart + UBound(arArr, 1)) - 1)
    RelativeColLevelEnd = ((RelativeColLevelStart + UBound(arArr, 2)) - 1)
    Debug.Print "The evaluated Row-Range of the result-array is now: " & RelativeRowLevelStart & " to " & RelativeRowLevelEnd
    Debug.Print "The evaluated Col-Range of the result-array is now: " & RelativeColLevelStart & " to " & RelativeColLevelEnd

    ' COMBINE now range-array and result-array
    Debug.Print "TypeName(arr): " & TypeName(arr)
    Debug.Print "TypeName(arArr): " & TypeName(arArr)
    If (IsEmpty(arArr)) Then
        Debug.Print "arArr is empty!"
    End If
    arrStart = Array(RelativeRowLevelStart, RelativeColLevelStart)
    Debug.Print "TypeName(arrStart): " & TypeName(arrStart)
    arr = WriteIntoArray(arr, arArr, arrStart)

    Debug.Print "Fertig combined...."

    ' saving the last relative positions of array for the next loop
    LastRelativeRowLU = RelativeRowLU
    LastRelativeColLU = RelativeColLU
    LastRelativeRowBR = RelativeRowBR
    LastRelativeColBR = RelativeColBR

    ' saving the last absolute positions of array for the next loop
    LastAbsoluteRowLU = AbsoluteRowLU
    LastAbsoluteColLU = AbsoluteColLU

    ' saving the dimensions of the result-array
    RowHeight = NewRowHeight
    ColWidth = NewColWidth

    ' increasing counters
    nr = nr + 1
Next ar

End Function
```

---

```
Function WriteIntoArray(A As Variant, B As Variant, Optional InsertCell As Variant) As Variant

If (IsMissing(InsertCell)) Then
    InsertCell = Array(1, 1)
End If

Dim lb As Long, ub_r_A As Long, ub_c_A As Long
Dim lb_r_B As Long, lb_c_B As Long
Dim ub_r_B As Long, ub_c_B As Long
Dim r_Max As Long, c_Max As Long, r_start As Long, c_start As Long, r_offset As Long, c_offset As Long
Dim m As Long, n As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim C As Variant

'If TypeName(A) = "Range" Then A = A.Value
'If TypeName(B) = "Range" Then B = B.Value
Debug.Print "TypeName(A): " & TypeName(A)
Debug.Print "TypeName(B): " & TypeName(B)

lb = LBound(A, 1)
ub_r_A = UBound(A, 1)
ub_c_A = UBound(A, 2)
lb_r_B = LBound(B, 1)
lb_c_B = LBound(B, 2)
ub_r_B = UBound(B, 1)
ub_c_B = UBound(B, 2)

r_start = InsertCell(0)
c_start = InsertCell(1)
r_offset = (r_start - 1)
c_offset = (c_start - 1)
r_Max = ((r_start + ub_r_B) - 1)
c_Max = ((c_start + ub_c_B) - 1)


' test size of arrays: B is not to be bigger
If ((ub_r_A < r_Max) Or (ub_c_A < c_Max)) Then
    WriteIntoArray = False
    Exit Function
End If

' prepare Copy-Process
m = ub_r_A
n = ub_c_A + ub_c_B + 1 - lb

' start Copy-Process
'ReDim C(lb To m, lb To n)
C = A
For i = lb_r_B To ub_r_B ' step every row
    For j = lb_c_B To ub_c_B ' work every cell in column
        'Debug.Print "Read from B (Cell '" & i & "/" & j & "'): '" & B(i, j) & "'"
        'Debug.Print "Write into C (Cell '" & i + r_offset & "/" & j + c_offset & "')" & B(i, j) & "'"
        C((i + r_offset), (j + c_offset)) = B(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

WriteIntoArray = C

End Function
```

Comment: please share the complete section of code around the area.

Comment: `Dim arr As Variant` not `Dim arr() As Variant`